# C++ Header File Errors

Tags: header, c++-cli, wrapper

I have been tasked to create a C# interface with some of the methods that are being using in the Open Source CrytoLib C++ project. I am trying to create a managed wrapper for the LIB file... however I am getting some errors already and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong as this seems pretty straightforward to this point.

My header file:

```
// CryptoLibWrapper.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace CryptoLibWrapper {

public ref class DefaultDecryptorWithMAC
{
public:
    BOOL Decrypt(BYTE const* pEncrypted, UINT uLength, BYTE** ppBuffer, DWORD* pdwLength);
};
}
```

The errors I am getting...

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BYTE'
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Decrypt'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

It has been a while since I have done any C++ and even that was limited, hoping this is easy and I am just being brain dead.

Thanks again!

EDIT: Note... all of the errors are at the "BOOL Decrypt..." line

Comment: Is this `ref` an extension of the compiler you're using? Because it is definitely not standard C++. Also, the BYTE, UINT etc. almost certainly are defined in a header not mentioned by you (they are not part of the standard language). Or maybe your problem is that you just forgot to include that header? Another thing I just notice: The `public` at namespace level certainly doesn't belong there. Namespaces don't support access specifications.

Comment: C4430 doesn't have a very good description text.  It means that the compiler found what could be a variable name without a type.  For example, if `BOOL` was undefined, it would think it saw two identifier declarations, neither with a type added.  Since K&R C allowed variables to be defined without a type (`int` assumed), the error message assumes that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndersK.: Thanks. When I commented, it was still tagged as C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're probably getting the first error because you're missing some type definitions.  The other errors are probably just as a result of those missing definitions.

You need to include a file that defines BYTE.  Putting this at the top of your file should do the job:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

or if you don't care about pulling in the whole of the windows headers, you could try:

```
#include <windef.h>
```

Comment: I would suggest against including `<windows.h>` in header files if possible, unless those header files are windows-specific.

Comment: That was it... arghh... must not have saved my include in my Stdafx.h file like I thought. Thank you (was hoping it would be that obvious!)

Comment: Using `#include <windef.h>` will cause compile errors. Use `#include <windows.h>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's telling you that it doesn't recognize the type BYTE - that could be causing the errors after that. So you need to either define BYTE before your class declaration or you need to #include the header file that defines BYTE. The rest of your definition looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

`BYTE` is user-defined type, therefore you need to include a header file that defines it. The header file that defines Windows data types is [`<WinDef.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

Answer (score 1):

You are a C# programmer, aren't you ;-). It looks like you just copied the C# style "using System;" If this is the case, you need to

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
```

before

```
using namespace System;
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI

But please, never use "using namespace" inside a header file.