# C++ include second form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

[Visual C++ Opening a second form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728015/visual-c-opening-a-second-form)

I tried this , but I have a problem

Form1.h

```
panel^ form2 = gcnew panel;
form2->ShowDialog();
```

panel.h

```
#include "Form1.h"
```

Form1.cpp and panel.cpp

```
#include "Form1.h"
#include "panel.h"
```

Error

```
 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'panel' 
 error C2065: 'form2' : undeclared identifier
 error C2065: 'form2' : undeclared identifier
 error C2065: 'panel' : undeclared identifier
 error C2227: left of '->ShowDialog' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you haven't included the headers for Panel.
Include the header where the panel type is declared and compile code.
All errors are due to missing panel declaration

Comment: Sorry, "panel" is name of second form (Form2). Corrected.

Comment: Still i will suggest you to include the header file where panel class is declare..see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096898/c-header-file-errors for reference

Comment: Now I have this error: C2039: 'ShowDialog' : is not a member of 'panel'

Comment: Have you declared ShowDialog as a member of panel class??

Comment: I don't have knowledge of managed c++, but still i will try to suggest you something like below

Class panel {
<return type> ShowDialog();
};